# PySpark comparing time (only) against a time variable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Well, I thought this would be very easy but I'm having trouble comparing time values.

e.g

Having a col with time (only) and a string variable e.g ***after_lunch = '13:00:00'*** I am trying to create the ***is_late*** col as below:

```
+--------------------+
|time_only| is_late  |
+--------------------+
| 12:46:40|      No  |
| 13:05:47|      Yes |
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the times to timestamp type first:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'is_late', 
    F.when(
        F.to_timestamp('time_only', 'H:mm:ss') > F.to_timestamp(F.lit('13:00:00'), 'H:mm:ss'), 
        'yes'
    ).otherwise('no')
)
```